# Different InfoWidget.xml for App Widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

i have a question about the app widget in android. I'm a litte bit confused, cause i define in the info xml (res -> xml) the values for width (250) and height (110) (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html). Now i expected my Widget take the in the width 4 cells and in the height 2 cells.

I tested it with a Nexus S (HDPI), all works fine, i tested it with a Nexus 4 (XHDPI), all works fine, i tested it with an Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1/Emulator tablets (MDPI), it doesn't work, Nexus7 (Emulator) (TVDPI) also it didn't work.

OK, I looked in the Menu and i see the system takes 3 and not 4 cells for the width.

Now my Question is there a way to define specific xml files for the tablets (please notice that i would support device with android 2.3.3) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting your layout for the widgets into different folders, so that it will be rendered out differently on different screen sizes?  For example, when supporting tablets you would have a layout-xlarge folder which contains the layout for your Widget on extra large screens.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) for more information about Tablet layouts.

Comment: No i don't do that, cause i understand this, thats for reason if i have declare some dp's in my layout but in my layout i work with weightsum and i also have created for mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi different buttons-size. The Big Problem for me is, that android don't use the 4 cells that i expected.

Comment: Yes, but there are two different dimensions here: screen density and screen size.  Screen density is the dpi, and you have accounted for that.  However, there is also screen size, which is independent of pixel density and measures how wide across the users' screen is.  For example, you can have a hdpi device with a large screen and an mdpi device with a large screen.

Comment: OK, thank u very much that was it. Let me show u, i have mess the size and these are the results mdpi=363, hdpi=455, xhdpi 558. Now the result i must create new mdpi graphics.